# Расположение модуля

Tags: битрикс

Куда необходимо поместить свой модуль?
В оф. туториалах пишут, что его необходимо разместить в папке local, но таковой у меня нет. В папке `bitrix/modules/` размещаются, в основном, модули, скачанные из marketplace.

Версия 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 17.5.10.

Comment: вопрос решился. 
у кого нет папки /local - просто создайте ее в корне проекта. не в корне папки /bitrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто создайте в корне сайте папку local и далее папку modules

Вообще вы должны работать ТОЛЬКО в папке local и шаблоны /local/templates/ и компоненты свои тоже в /local/components/

Есть некоторые рекомендации, что сторонние PHP библиотеки (PHPExcel например), желательно держать в /local/vendors/ , но это уже не обязательное правило, а просто хороший тон в программинге на битриксе, чтобы другой программист не тратил 100500 часов чтобы найти ваши дополнения.