# Добавление пунктов управления собственным модулем в административное меню

Tags: битрикс

Имеется собственный модуль для Битрикса. Нужно добавить управление им в административную панель. Где нужно прописать код для добавление пунктов меню в административной панели?

Comment: Что? Вы о чем? Какого модуля? Какое меню? Где находится include.php? Прочитайте про то как задавать вопросы на этом ресурсе [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Вы уже задавали подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790432/) и Вам на него ответили. Вы всегда можете отредактировать и дополнить свой вопрос. Не плодите дубликаты.

Comment: тот вопрос касался размещения модуля в структуре битрикса.
в данном вопросе спрашивается о том, в каком файле из структуры кастомного модуля описывать добавления пункта меню в админке на сайте

Comment: понял Ваш вопрос.

Comment: немного подправил чтобы было понятнее чего вы добиваетесь

Answer (score 2):

Образец структуры меню на примере `\bitrix\modules\main\admin\menu.php`

```
$aMenu[] = array(
   "parent_menu" => "global_menu_settings",
   "sort" => 1800,
   "text" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_TOOLS"),
   "title" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_TOOLS_TITLE"),
   "url" => "tools_index.php?lang=".LANGUAGE_ID,
   "icon" => "util_menu_icon",
   "page_icon" => "util_page_icon",
   "items_id" => "menu_util",
   "items" => array(
      array(
         "text" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_SITE_CHECKER"),
         "url" => "site_checker.php?lang=".LANGUAGE_ID,
         "more_url" => array(),
         "title" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_SITE_CHECKER_ALT"),
      ),
      array(
         "text" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_FILE_CHECKER"),
         "url" => "file_checker.php?lang=".LANGUAGE_ID,
         "more_url" => array(),
         "title" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_FILE_CHECKER_ALT"),
      ),
      array(
         "text" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_PHPINFO"),
         "url" => "phpinfo.php?test_var1=AAA&test_var2=BBB",
         "more_url" => array("phpinfo.php"),
         "title" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_PHPINFO_ALT"),
      ),
      array(
         "text" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_SQL"),
         "url" => "sql.php?lang=".LANGUAGE_ID."&del_query=Y",
         "more_url" => array("sql.php"),
         "title" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_SQL_ALT"),
      ),
      array(
         "text" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_PHP"),
         "url" => "php_command_line.php?lang=".LANGUAGE_ID."",
         "more_url" => array("php_command_line.php"),
         "title" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_PHP_ALT"),
      ),
      array(
         "text" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_AGENT"),
         "url" => "agent_list.php?lang=".LANGUAGE_ID,
         "more_url" => array("agent_list.php", "agent_edit.php"),
         "title" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_AGENT_ALT"),
      ),
      array(
         "text" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_DUMP"),
         "url" => "dump.php?lang=".LANGUAGE_ID,
         "more_url" => array("dump.php", "restore_export.php"),
         "title" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_DUMP_ALT"),
      ),
(strtoupper($DBType) == "MYSQL"?
   Array(
      "text" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_REPAIR_DB"),
      "url" => "repair_db.php?lang=".LANGUAGE_ID,
      "more_url" => array(),
      "title" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_REPAIR_DB_ALT"),
   )
:null
),
($USER->CanDoOperation('view_event_log')?
   Array(
      "text" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_EVENT_LOG"),
      "url" => "event_log.php?lang=".LANGUAGE_ID,
      "more_url" => array(),
      "title" => GetMessage("MAIN_MENU_EVENT_LOG_ALT"),
   )
:null
      ),
   ),
);
```

Пример добавления произвольного меню с помощью файла `/bitrix/admin/.left.menu.php` :

```
<?
// добавим пункт меню "Импорт техники" в раздел "Информ. блоки"
$aMenuLinks = Array(
    Array(
        "Импорт техники", 
        "/bitrix/admin/equipment_import.php?lang=ru", 
        Array(), 
        Array(
            "ALT" => "Импорт техники из dbf файлов", 
            "SECTION_ID" => "iblock",
            "SORT" => "100"
        )
    )
);
```

Для добавления пунктов в административное меня можно также использовать событие [OnBuildGlobalMenu](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onbuildglobalmenu.php)

Если вы пишите свой модуль можете использовать `/bitrix/modules/ID_модуля/admin/menu.php` для добавление пунктов административного меню.

Подробнее о работе с Битриксом как разработчику почитайте в [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43).

Ну а вообще в первой же ссылке в поиске гугла по запросу "[битрикс добавление модуля в админку](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%B2+%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83)" есть нужные Вам ответы.